# SpaCy 3 Transformer Vector Token Alignment

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I'm using the SpaCy `3.0.1` together with the transformer model (`en_core_web_trf`).
When I previously used SpaCy transformers it was possible to get the transformer vectors from a `Token` or `Span`.
In SpaCy 3 however it seems like you can only access the transformer vectors via the `Doc` (`doc._.trf_data`) without a proper alignment to the SpaCy tokens.

How can I get the alignment between SpaCy Tokens and Vectors/Wordpieces? 
Or alternatively; is there some function that allows you to directly get the vectors for a `Token` or `Span`?

Answer (score 9):

When having a `doc`:

```
doc = nlp("Helsinki is the capital of Finland.")
```

Where the wordpieces are:

```
[['<s>',
  'H',
  'els',
  'inki',
  'Ġis',
  'Ġthe',
  'Ġcapital',
  'Ġof',
  'ĠFinland',
  '.',
  '</s>']]
```

Then you can access the alignment for example for the first token using the following code:

```
# Get the first spaCy Token, "Helsinki", and its alignment data
doc[0], doc._.trf_data.align[0].data
```

Output:

```
(Helsinki,
 array([[1],
        [2],
        [3]], dtype=int32))
```

Then you can use these indices to extract the respective vectors from `doc._.trf_data.tensors`.

---

**Source**:

*https://applied-language-technology.mooc.fi/html/notebooks/part_iii/04_embeddings.html*

*(Provides also more detailed explanations and information about the usage of transformer in spacy)*